# Terraform: connection block with double bastion

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

is it possible in terraform to create a 3 level connection with 2 bastions?
I mean:
bastion1 --> bastion2 --> instance

I need to cover that use case but I see in documentation how to do it only with 1 bastion.

Or if not supported, is there a workaround to achive this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need this type of chaining? Is there a reason you can't just go directly from your bastion to the target instance?

Comment: Because network policies we have, we cannot perform direct ssh to outside ips, but I have a whitelisted external IP in AWS that I can use as bastion1, but the bastion2 (with public IP) and final instance (only private IP) are in separated vpc. Bastion1 does not have direct access to instance, and I dont have direct access to bastion2 (only via bastion1).